# I'm getting an Exception when trying to create a RayCast in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the line

```
Ray ray =
Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

taken word for word from the Unity documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html

But I keep getting an error saying

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Heres the full Method as well

```
void Update()
    {
      Movement();
      GetInput();

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
    RemoveFocus();
}
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,100))
    {

        //check if we hit our interactable object
        Interactable interactable= hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        //if we did set it as out focus
        if(interactable!=null)
        {
            SetFocus(interactable);

        }
    }

}
```

}

Please Help?

Comment: which line is giving you that exception?

Comment: @AviadHasidof The line  `Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);` The one i took straight from documentation

Comment: is there a Camera tagged as `main` in your scene (ie. can you `Debug.Log(Camera.main)` what does it return)? If it's `null`, remove your `Camera` object from scene and add a new one again.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko oh thank you, that worked! I had a camera but i didn't have it tagged as main and once i did, the error went away thank you!!